# How to resolve Could not serialize object Caused error while using cache scope in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

I have added caching scope in my flow for response of the http request. before caching scope i have a set-variable component that has the json object becasue of that i'm getting error. when i am removing the 
set-variable it's working. How can i resolve the issue even i am using set-variable?

Error:

```
 com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.cache.internal.ObjectStoreCachingStrategy: Unable to store event in cache
 org.mule.runtime.api.store.ObjectStoreException: Could not serialize object Caused by: 
 org.mule.runtime.api.serialization.SerializationException: Could not serialize object
```

flow:

```
<flow name="tokenFlow" doc:id="cb6d9de3-45fa-47f0-b2f5-875048d0b980" ><http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="36c16957-47c1-4d07-b6c2-694e6c86a9f3" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/fssvc-api/collectionSFDCInbound"/>
    <set-variable value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="3f372591-b02a-4d82-a634-159b865090ca" variableName="request" />
    <ee:cache doc:name="Cache" doc:id="ae4c75b2-5e92-4578-9966-1277b47b472a" cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy1">
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" doc:id="08d40c87-8f60-4b4e-8e20-1c93c1b52477" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" url="https://idfcfirstbank--colqaorg.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?">
        <http:query-params><![CDATA[#[output
  application/java
   ---
 {
"password" : "test",
"grant_type" : "password",
"client_secret" : "test1234",
"client_id" : "1234",
"username" : "test@gmail.com"
}]]]></http:query-params>
    </http:request>
    </ee:cache>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is described in the KB article https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Mule-4-flow-variable-causing-ObjectStoreException

As it explains, you could convert the variable to a String to avoid the serialization issue.

Example:

```
<set-variable value="#[output application/java --- payload as String]" ...>
```

Since Mule 4.3.0 the scope of information stored in the cache has been narrowed so migrating the version of Mule to the last one is a solution.

Comment: Hi @aled  one issue i'm facing with this approach is the long value is converting into double i can i avoid this?

Comment: You should ask a new question for that.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. and the KB Article didn't suggests a clear solution ( It was a guessing game)

Comment: Based on my recent experience that issue is resolved in 4.3 runtime( got the patch for my runtime 4.2.2) from mulesoft support. It works for me

Comment: I had this happen to me recently, when I tried to cache the result of a call to a SOAP web service via the Web Service Consumer connector.  The problem seems to be that the Cache processor wants to cache the complete message, not just the payload about to be returned - and the attributes of the message object were set to be an instance of SoapAttributes by the Consumer, which is not Serializable.  I haven't found a way around it, yet :-(.  This is using the Mule 4.4 EE runtime.

Comment: That should have been resolved in previous versions. You should report the issue to MuleSoft.

Comment: @moilejter Now There is one option called Filter in cache scope, can use those to exclude attributes on the cache.

Comment: @star - I hadn't seen that, but I am not sure it would help me, since I would need to avoid serializing the complete attributes object altogether, not just any/all of its properties.

Answer (score 1):

My scenario was a little more complicated, in that the issue for me was that, at the time I wanted to serialize the message to the cache, it had already been replaced by the result of a SOAP call - and that replaces the attributes property of the message with an instance of SoapAttributes, which is not Java Serializable.
The solution that worked for me was to get my Mule app to use the Kryo serializer, instead - which doesn't care whether the object to be saved is Serializable.
The two entries in my config are:

```
   <kryo:serializer name="kryo" compressionMode="GZIP" />
   <configuration defaultObjectSerializer-ref="kryo" />
```

You can read about it [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/improving-performance-with-the-kryo-serializer).